# How to quickly append multiple lines to div (one at a time) and scroll to bottom using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

I'd like to monitor the output log of a job that's run on my webserver by watching it in the browser.  I'm using websockets to send the output of the job to a Vue element.  The output is sent line by line and I'd like to append the newest line to the Vue element and scroll to the bottom of the div to emulate running tail -f on the job output file.

It works, but if the lines are sent rapidly the browser CPU usage goes very high and the page is very slow to render.  In Chrome DevTools I can see my websockets messages coming in just fine in real time.  So I'm obviously not efficiently adding each line to the Vue element.

What is a more efficient way to append text line by line to a vue element and continuously scroll to the bottom?

Or should I buffer the websocket messages and process several lines at once?

```
<div id="job_output_vue" class="wordwrap">
    <pre>{{text}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
    var logSocket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.host + '/ws/jobOutput/');

    logSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    if (data.line!==undefined)
        {
        appLog.appendText(data.line);
        }
    }

    var appLog = new Vue({
            el: '#job_output_vue',
            data: {
            text: ""
        },
        methods:
        {
            appendText(newText) {
                this.text = this.text + newText;
                this.scrollToEnd();
                },
            scrollToEnd() {
                var container = this.$el;
                container.scrollTop=container.scrollHeight;
                }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.appendText("Loading...");
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
        },
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the scrolling is the expensive operation here. Something you could try would be adding a watcher for the `text` property, and handle the scrolling there:

```
...
methods: {
  appendText(newText) {
    this.text = this.text + newText;
  },
  scrollToEnd() {
    var container = this.$el;
    container.scrollTop=container.scrollHeight;
  }
},
watch: {
  text() {
    this.scrollToEnd();
  }
},
mounted() {
  var vm = this;
  this.appendText("Loading...");
},
```

I haven't tried this out, but I'm curious to know if it is more performant than what you started with. Let me know if this works!

Comment: You're right!  It is the scrolling that's slowing it down.  But it seems that onresize isn't getting called at all in your answer.  The div stays the same size, it's just getting more content added to it.

Comment: Shoot... Ok, try the updated solution, which uses a watcher instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that's similar performance to the original.  I implemented a counter and only scrolled to the bottom every 25 lines and that works without freezing the browser, but it's not the smooth looking at the terminal feel that I was hoping for.

Comment: Interestingly if I move the scroll command out of the Vue definition it works fine:  appLog.$el.scrollTop = appLog.$el.scrollHeight; (in websocket onmessage).